# Show/hide divs based on values selected in multiple select2 dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a search result filtering feature. I have a number of *select2* dropdown boxes where the user can select multiple values from to either hide or show `div`s with matching class values. I have a number of `div`s with classes containing values matching values in the *select2* dropdown boxes. How do I go about coding this functionality?

I can only get this to work for one selection, I'd like to be able to select multiple options from the dropdowns.

```js
$('select.filterCandidates').bind('change', function() {
  $('select.filterCandidates').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $('#candidates').find('.row').hide();
  var critriaAttribute = '';

  $('select.filterCandidates').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '0') {
      critriaAttribute += '[data-' + $(this).data('attribute') + '*="' + $(this).val() + '"]';
    }
  });

  $('#candidates').find('.row' + critriaAttribute).show();
  $('#filterCount').html('Showing ' + $('div#candidates div.row:visible').length + ' Matches');
  $('select.filterCandidates').removeAttr('disabled');
});

$('#reset-filters').on("click", function() {
  $('#candidates').find('.row').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <br>
    <h4>Search Form</h4>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select id="type" class="form-control filterCandidates" data-attribute="type">
        <option value="0">Candidate Type</option>
        <option value="CA">CA</option>
        <option value="CFA">CFA</option>
        <option value="CFO">CFO</option>
        <option value="CIMA">CIMA</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select id="role" class="form-control filterCandidates" data-attribute="role">
        <option value="0">Preferred Role</option>
        <option value="Analyst">Analyst</option>
        <option value="Associate">Associate</option>
        <option value="CFO">CFO</option>
        <option value="FD">FD</option>
        <option value="FM">FM</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select id="roleType" class="form-control filterCandidates" data-attribute="roleType">
        <option value="0">Preferred Role Type</option>
        <option value="Permanent">Permanent</option>
        <option value="Contract/Interim">Contract/Interim</option>
        <option value="Internship">Internship</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527)

Comment: @Phiter I've updated the question, apologies, I hit submit before I could add the code.

Answer (score 0):

just to give you a rough idea as you have not provided any code.

```
<script>
   var SelectedValues = $('#ddlSelect option:selected');
   var NotSelectedValues $('#ddlSelect option:not(:selected)');
        $(SelectedValues ).each(function () {
        $("."+$(this).val()+"").show(); //show all those divs containing 
        //this class

        });
        $(NotSelectedValues ).each(function () {
        $("."+$(this).val()+"").hide();//hide all those divs containing 
        //this class

        });
</script>
```

This is a rough idea , The above script will show all of the divs containing the classes you have selected in your select2 with id "ddlSelect" and hide those which you have not selected.
you can put this into a function and call it on onchange event of ddlSelect or whatever and however you want it to.

Comment: I don't think it will, not as it is written.

Comment: and what makes you think that ?

Comment: The selector for both show/hide is wrongly concatenated.